# apostrophe not well interpreted in jsp

Tags: jsp, utf-8

Edit :
In my jsp (that uses UTF-8), I have :

```
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="<%=resourcebundle.getString("login.Username")%>"onblur="this.placeholder = '<%=resourcebundle.getString("login.Username")%>'"
```

And in my properties file I have :

```
login.Username=Nom d'utilisateur
```

This property that contains apostrophe doesn't cause problem in placeholder but causes problem in onblur function : an error is diplayed in Firebug : “Missing ; before statement”

I so replaced my code in .properties file by :

```
login.Username=Nom d\'utilisateur
```

So I get no longer error in Firebug. But the problem now is that, at the first time in the browser the world is displayed : Nom d\'utilisateur, due to placeholder. I guess to use two different properties for placeholder and on blur :

```
login.Username=Nom d'utilisateur
login.Username.blur=Nom d\'utilisateur
```

And in jsp :

```
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder=" <%=resourcebundle.getString("login.Username")%>"onblur="this.placeholder = '<%=resourcebundle.getString("login.Username.blur")%>'"
```

Is there a better way to do things ?

Comment: Or you can write an EL function for escaping apostrophe!!!

Comment: I edited the problem. Please see it.